# SO last page bug

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

Is this a SO bug? try to open https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tagnames=c%23 than go to last page(188 when I got this), page numbers are lost and it is difficult to go to the previous page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try refreshing and scrolling down? Works for me, but the pages are down at the footer.

Chrome on WinXP here...

By the way, he's only viewing 15 questions per page, to get to #188.

Comment: Same result on Opera 9.63

Comment: oops yes, there are exists, but in the deep bottom of the page :) I think it will be better if they will be under the grid