# Can't see the page coming before the last page

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, pagination

I click on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Then I go to the last page clicking on 22 (I use 50 results by page) at the bottom of the page. 
Everything is fine.

Then I click on 21 to see the previous page. The page is blank showing no result.

I have the same behavior when I click on 18, 19 and 20.

I tried to refresh the page [as specified here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/so-last-page-bug), same result.

I use firefox 4.0.1 and IE 8.0.6001.18702CO on WinXP

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93502/page-without-answers-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Obviously, it`s not a bug. Should I re-tag the question ?

Comment: I think it is still a bug. The page count should reflect the answers you can actually see.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now, I see only 8 pages when viewing as visitor. Can you please confirm it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I see 8 pages too. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, flagged for status completed then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't verify since I don't have 10K on SO, but I suspect that those pages are full of deleted posts which are not visible if you have < 10K rep.

Comment: Dozens of deleted answers, some very highly downvoted.